# How to compute the error of the Taylor series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$ \sin(x) \approx x-\frac{x^3}{6},\quad 0\le x \le 1 $$

I still don't know, how does this method work, I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the general Taylor series:

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\dots+(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+\dots$$

Clearly, for $x\in[0,1]$, we have an [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series) with monotonically decreasing terms, therefore, the partial sum has error bounded by the next term:

$$P_3(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}$$

$$|\sin(x)-P_3(x)|\le\frac{x^5}{5!}$$

---

To estimate the error for a non-alternating series, I recommend watching this series of Videos from Khan Academy:

[Taylor polynomial remainder](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/taylor-series-calc/v/error-or-remainder-of-a-taylor-polynomial-approximation)

Answer (score 2):

**I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that uses the integral form of the remainder. To that end, we proceed.**

---

We can write $\sin(x)$ as

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac16 x^3+\frac1{24}\int_0^x t^4\cos(x-t)\,dt \tag 1$$

---

> It is a straightforward task to develop $(1)$ by starting with the relationship $\sin(x)=\int_0^x \cos(x-t)\,dt$ and repeatedly integrating by parts.  In fact, this procedure can be generalized to any function $f(x)=f(a)+\int_0^{x-a}f'(x-t)\,dt$ to develop the [Taylor's Formula with integral remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).

---

Using $(1)$, we have the estimates of the error of $|\sin(x)-x+\frac16x^3|$ for $x\in [0,1]$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sin(x)-x+\frac16x^3\right|&=\left|\frac1{24}\int_0^x t^4\cos(x-t)\,dt\right|\\\\
&\le \frac1{24}\int_0^x |t^4\,\cos(x-t)|\,dt\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{120}x^5\\\\
&\le \frac1{120}
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\left|\sin(x)-x+\frac16x^3\right|\le \frac1{120}$$

for $x\in[0,1]$.